# "Истина заканчивается там, где начинаются деньги". Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Истина заканчивается там, где начинаются деньги.

Правильно ли поставлена запятая?

Comment: Ну очень же просто... Две основы, запятая их разделяет.

Comment: Вопрос может остаться без ответа из-за его (ответа ) очевидности.

Comment: Есть люди, для которых подобное не просто. К счастью, вопрос без ответа не остался.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Истина заканчивается там, где начинаются деньги.**

Запятая стоит на месте. Единственный неправильный вариант –
 это поставить ее перед местоимением ТАМ (интонационно такой вариант возможен).

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с местоименной связью и придаточным места. ТАМ – указательное слово, где – союзное слово.

Союзного соединения ТАМ ГДЕ не существует.

Сравнить: составные союзы  ОТТОГО ЧТО, ПОТОМУ ЧТО можно расчленять или не расчленять запятой.